# 質問者に報酬を。

Tags: サポート, stackoverflow.blog

これは [Sara Chipps](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/schipps/) 氏によって 2019 年 11 月 13 日に投稿された ["We’re Rewarding the Question Askers"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) の和訳です。

---

私の最初の[ブログ記事](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/18/building-community-inclusivity-stack-overflow/)で、Stack Overflow のコミュニティについて私に教えてくれた個人的経験について書きました。そして、我々は今までしてきたことを振り返り、フィードバックをどのように行い、コンテンツの質をどう高められ、人々の間の摩擦を如何に減らせるかを再評価すると言いました。我々の目標は質問をするプロセスの苦痛を減らすこと、そして Stack Overflow のベテランにも新人にも同じように得があるようにすることです。

この再評価に伴い、我々は信用度の付与システムに目を付けました。回答に +1 投票された人は +10 の信用度を得ますが、質問に +1 投票された人は +5 の信用度しか得られません。

どうしてこうなっているのでしょうか。Stack Overflow が立ち上がった 2007 年、我々は質問と回答両方に等しい信用度を与えていました。3年後、質問に対する信用度を減らす決定がなされました。この変更によって質問をすることよりも良質な回答を書くことに集中させたい、というのが主な理由でした。

今となってみると、この決定についてそれからどうなったかも含めて考えることができます。その時点で与えられていた情報から考えるとこの決定は正しかったかもしれませんが、我々はその後コミュニティにどんな影響があったのかを知っています。我々は質問者より回答者に報酬を与えたのです。

Stack Overflow のコミュニティに長くいる者として、私は「良い質問をする」のが難しいことを知っています。皆さんの中の多くもそうでしょう。良い質問をするには、その人が抱えている問題を上手く伝えるための思慮深さと注意力が必要です。一度立ち止まり、自分の状況について全く知らない人に問題を説明するよう振る舞う必要があります。聞く側の人間は自分のコンパイルログを見てくれませんし、自分が作っている機能について知りません。どんなライブラリを使っていて、どんなバージョンのフレームワークが自分のマシンに入っているかも知らないのです。

無関係な情報もたくさんあると自覚する必要もあります。エラーメッセージのどの部分を含めるべきか知っておく必要がありますし、どの部分が自分のマシン特有のものなのかも分かっている必要があります。それまで何をしてきたかの手順を含める必要もありますし、テストで試してみた結果を含める必要もあります。要するに、とても良い回答を確実に得るためには、質問をするエキスパートにならないといけないのです。これにはスキルと経験が必要です。これは価値があるもので、我々が評価したいと思っているものです。

そこで本日から、設定を元に戻します。質問に対する +1 投票によって得られる信用度を +10 点にし、回答に対する +1 投票によって得られる点数と一緒にします。

更にそれぞれの Stack Overflow と Stack Exchange サイトにおいて、この変更にもとづき信用度を再計算します。質問に対して昔行われた +1 投票も遡及的に +10 信用度になります。

英語版 Stack Overflow においては、おおよそ 240 万人が更なる信用度を得ると見積もっています。この変更は信用度だけの問題ではありません。我々はここに明らかなメッセージとして伝えたいです。我々は質問者をお祝いします。 **おめでとう！　質問をするすべての人！**

新しい権限を得る方々へは、その責を謹んで受け取っていただきたいです。あなたは質問をするエキスパートです。自分が取り組んでいる問題を特定することができ、キーボードの向こう側にいる人にとってそれがどれだけ難しいか知っている人材なのです。是非質問者が上手く質問できるよう優しく教えてあげてください。

質問者と回答者の両方が我々のエコシステムの生命線であると、我々は信じています。歴史上最もたくさん技術向け Q&A を蓄えているこのサイトに対して質問者と回答者が為してきたことに感謝し、このサイトができてから今までに至るすべての貢献に感謝します。

我々は更に行動します。

英語版 Stack Overflow において質問体験を良くする機能をリリースしました（Stack Exchange site では Q1 に実施される予定です）。8月に Meg Risdal が[この改善をプレビューしてくれました](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/08/20/upcoming-on-stack-overflow/)し、9月に Lisa Park がその改善を開発するにあたっての調査の[舞台裏](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/26/research-update-improving-the-question-asking-experience/)について書いてくれました。この機能が皆さんも使えるようになるのを楽しみにしています！

昨日、Julia Silge が新機能の A/B テストの結果を[要約してくれました](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/12/research-update-a-b-testing-the-new-question-form/)。これによると、質問をし始めそして投稿した人の数が確かに増加しています。我々は質問の質についても調査し（というのも、質問するすべての人に回答が来やすいようにしたいからです）、質問の質が落ちていないことも確認しました。

再び繰り返しますが、私と Community Team は、どんなレベルのプログラマーでも Stack Overflow での体験が向上することにわくわくしています。初めてフロントエンドを学ぶ新規ユーザーから、20年以上コードを書いているような熟達したモデレーターまで、全員です。質問の +1 投票に対する信用度を上げ、質問する体験を良くするという変更と、来週告知する新しいフィードバックの仕組みは、より良い Stack Overflow をコミュニティと手を取り合って作っていくための最高の一歩となるでしょう。

※英語ですが、新しいポッドキャストも公開しました。今までの全てのエピソードは[こちら](https://stackoverflow.blog/podcast/)。

https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/too-devto-quit

Comment: 英語版では既に反映されているみたいですが、日本語版だとまだのような気がします。

Comment: Nick Craverさんが再計算の[実況ツイートをなさっているようです](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1194719400349306880) =)

Answer (score 2):

英語版メタでの関連投稿です。現時点で -450 超のマイナス票で、コミュニティとしてはこの変更に対して非常に不評なようです。
(このところ英語版ではコミュニティとSO社とで対立の構図が出来上がってしまっている様子)

[Upvotes on questions will now be worth the same as upvotes on answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391250)